# Growing UserControl Size with Style Trigger?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, triggers, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I would like to cause a custom UserControl to grow by a multiplier when an "IsSelected" DP is set to true.  My current XAML looks like this:

```
<ctrl:MyBaseControl x:Class="MyDemo.Controls.MyCustomControl"
         ...>
<ctrl:MyBaseControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:MyCustomControl}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="340" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="260" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ctrl:MyBaseControl.Resources>
<Border>
    <StackPanel>
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

In the above sample, "MyBaseControl" extends UserControl, and defines the IsSelected DP.

This code just plain isn't working at the moment, which is one of my issues.  The other is that I would like to grow the Width/Height for a certain amount (for example: 0.10) instead of setting it to a hard number.  This way I can set the size when I define the control at the source.

Thanks for any help!

**ADDITION CODE:**

MyBaseControl Code:

```
public abstract class MyBaseControl: UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsSelected",
        typeof(Boolean),
        typeof(MyBaseControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MyBaseControl() : base() { }

    #region Properties

    public Boolean IsSelected
    {
        get { return (Boolean)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion Properties

}
```

MyCustomControl Code:

```
public partial class MyCustomControl: MyBaseControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Icon",
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(MyCustomControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BlurbProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Blurb",
        typeof(String),
        typeof(MyCustomControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Properties

    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    public String Blurb
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(BlurbProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BlurbProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion Properties
}
```

Example of working trigger on internal elements:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:MyCustomControl}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Could you post the code for your UserControl, and perhaps the code that manipulates the IsSelected DP?

Comment: Hi KDiTraglia, I've updated my post with additional code.

Comment: Is anything ever changing the state of IsSelected?  From the code posted it would appear as if it is always false (unless you didn't add the part that would change it)

Comment: I did not include the code, but it is being set (I do so by moving a custom cursor over the control).  I added another bit of code to the end that does work -- so I know the IsSelected is coming through.  I've tried similar variations on this working block to control the MyCustomControl itself, but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<ctrl:MyBaseControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:MyCustomControl}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform" >
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.1" ScaleY="1.1" />
                   </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ctrl:MyBaseControl.Resources>
```

Comment: I'm trying out a few variations of this, but so far the trigger is not firing.  I updated the - Property="IsSelected" - to - Binding="{Binding IsSelected}", but still no luck.  For whatever reason, things don't want to take action on the control itself.

Comment: Got it.  I updated the "DataTrigger" to a regular "Trigger".  I'm not sure what the difference is between what I have now, and what I originally posted, but it is at least working. :)  Side question - with the Transform, how can I get it to scale and keep the center point where it is (instead of the top-left point)?

Comment: Found it: <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5"/> -- thanks again KDiTraglia.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey Yeah I just figured that out myself, glad I could help (though I feel you did most of the heavy lifting yourself =))